# How to trigger firebase function on all database instances rather than default one?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have 50 realtime firebase database instances which are all identical.

Is it possible to get all my firebase functions to trigger on all instances, rather than just the default instance?

I know you can do this

```
exports.myWriteFunction = functions.database.instance('my-secondary-db').ref('path/to/data').onUpdate((snap, context) => { ... })
```

But I really want to run this function on every instance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to automatically associate a function with all database instances. You will have to associate it with each in your own code, although you can of course simply define a single function body that you associate all of them with:

```
const myfunc = (snap, context) => { ... }
exports.myWriteFunction1 = functions.database.instance('my-secondary-db').ref('path/to/data').onUpdate(myfunc)
exports.myWriteFunction2 = functions.database.instance('my-tertiary-db').ref('path/to/data').onUpdate(myfunc)
```

Comment: Can I export 2 functions with the same name?

Comment: If I can export 2 functions with the same name how does this count towards the 1000 function quota?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a copy/paste mistake. Updated now.