# How to use a secondary DB instance on Firebase local emulator with realtime database triggers / cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run Realtime Database triggers on **a secondary database instance** on the **local Firebase Emulator**. I have followed the examples in:

- [How do I setup firebase realtime DB triggers for multiple databases using cloud functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59171891/how-do-i-setup-firebase-realtime-db-triggers-for-multiple-databases-using-cloud)
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions#specify_the_instance_and_path

by specifying the `instance(dbInstanceId)` after the `functions.database`.

---

My functions' **package.json**:

```js
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.8.0"
  },
```

**Firebase version:**

```
$ firebase --version
8.6.0
```

**lib/index.ts**

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

const defaultDb = admin.database();

// default instance name is 'sgo-personal'
export const onStaffCreatedDefault = functions.database
  .ref('/staff/{name}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    defaultDb.ref('/meta/defaultDbCount').set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
    console.log("Hello from default instance DB");
    return null;
  });

export const onStaffCreatedDb1 = functions.database.instance('db1')
  .ref('/staff/{name}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    defaultDb.ref('/meta/db1Count').set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
    console.log("Hello from DB1");
    return null;
  });

export const onStaffCreatedDb2 = functions.database.instance('db2')
  .ref('/staff/{name}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    defaultDb.ref('/meta/db2Count').set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
    console.log("Hello from DB2");
    return null;
  });
```

---

**Question:** When I add data on the secondary database instance, it doesn't trigger anything. Is this a limitation of the local emulator?

If I add a staff on either `db1` or `db2` instances, no logs are printed.

But if I add a staff in the default instance, **all** the cloud functions are triggered based on the logs:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "onStaffCreatedDefault"
i  functions: Beginning execution of "onStaffCreatedDb2"
>  Hello from default instance DB
i  functions: Finished "onStaffCreatedDefault" in ~1s
i  functions: Beginning execution of "onStaffCreatedDb1"
i  functions: Finished "onStaffCreatedDb1" in ~1s
>  Hello from DB2
>  Hello from DB1
i  functions: Finished "onStaffCreatedDb2" in ~1s
```

Attached screenshot: [Firebase Emulator UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q45H.png)

I expected that `/sgo-personal/meta/db2Count` would be `2` after adding 2 records in `db2`.

Comment: If you have a bug to report with the Firebase CLI, you can do that on its repo.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: thanks! I logged in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2501.